# Checking whether the selected item in a combobox has been changed java

Tags: java

In my program I have several JComboBoxes which display different attributes of a bike. I currently have it set up so that the user can click a button called saveBike and save the attributes to a RandomAccessFile. I made my own listener for this button and added it to the JButton. All my listener does is open a JFileChooser and allow the user to save the file with the name of their choice. What I want my program to do is after the user saves the attributes with the given name, I want saveBike to be disabled so the user cannot keep clicking it. However, I want saveBike to be enabled again if the user changes one of the attributes by selecting something different in the ComboBox. I thought I could put this code in the listener, but I don't know how to see if an item was selected in the comboboxes or not. My question is, is there a way to see whether a NEW item in a combo box was selected or not.

Comment: You could add a listener to the JComboBox, which implements the itemStateChanged method, where you can enable the saveBike button.

Comment: I do have a listener added to my combobox, but it's my very own listener. Can i implement the itemstatechanged method in my own listener?

Comment: I have provided an example in the answer of how to use itemStateChanged method. You can just use an anonymous class to implement the itemStateChanged method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example explain how you can use an `ItemListener` to check when an item is selected, and enable a button if it is.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
            //elements to be shown in the combo box
        String course[] = {"", "A", "B", "C"};

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Creating a JComboBox Component");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();

        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox(course);

        final JButton button = new JButton("Save");
        panel.add(combo);
        panel.add(button);

            //disables the button at the start
        button.setEnabled(false);
        frame.add(panel);

        combo.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ie) {
                            //enables the button when an item is selected
                button.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
```